# Java - Markov Chain Text Generator - Parse text file

Tags: java, parsing, for-loop, while-loop, markov-chains

I need to create a Markov Chain Text Generator for my Algorithms class using a plaintext file of "The Tale of Two Cities" (courtesy of Project Gutenberg). I'm currently stuck on the first phase which is parsing through the text file and making key-value pairs out of the characters in order to add them to a symbol table in order to do the rest of the work (actually generate the new text).

To clarify, this is what I want for my key-value pairs (assuming the alphabet is the text file):

- abc = key | d = value
- bcd = key | e = value
- cde = key | f = value
- And so on

I'm using a BufferedReader to read each line and then parsing through each line, but the way I'm doing it is wrong and I can't figure out a way around it. In order to iterate over the characters in each line, I'm using a for loop to reach to the current character, then reaching the current character+1, and so on. Essentially, I end up having to reach to the next line (which hasn't been read yet) and receive a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception.
I need a way to move to the next line and continue my iteration over the entire file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MarkovTextGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /***********************************************************
         * Begin parsing through text file, character by character *
         ***********************************************************/
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                    String char1 = line.substring(i, i + 1);
                    String char2 = line.substring(i + 1, i + 2);
                    String char3 = line.substring(i + 2, i + 3);
                    char value = line.charAt(i + 3);
                    String key = char1 + char2 + char3;
                    System.out.println(key);
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        }
        /******************
         * End of parsing *
         ******************/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration of your for-loop should only go to `i < line.length() - 3`.  The `StringIndexOutOfBounds` exception is thrown because the `line.substring` calls will go past the last character of the string.

For example

`"abc".substring(2,3)` will throw an exception because there are no more characters left after the string.

Comment: Don't forget to add a special handling in case the line has three or less characters (the loop won't get executed at all if you check for `i < line.length() - 3` and `line.length()` returns a value `<=3`).

Comment: Thank you Niels! That did the trick. Also, thanks to @sina! That is an important thing to remember. However, I will not run into that issue with my specific program so I don't need to worry about it.